# Pick saving primitive Data in Android

Tags: android, file, exception, permissions, save

I am trying to save some arrays in an application to use them in other platform (C++) are serialized. I use a pick method to let the user choose the file name and directory, but first I am trying to define the root directory like this, since the handling of the Create Document needs Android 10 to start in the proper defined directory:

'''

```
     String a = getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            try {

                String public_dir = "sistemaderiegoandroid_arduino" + MyDocuments.fileSeparator;
                file = new File(a, public_dir);

                file.setWritable(true);

                    if (!file.mkdirs()) {

                        file.mkdir();

                    }
                    ;
                    DocumentsContract.createDocument(context.getContentResolver(), DocumentsContract.buildRootUri(MyDocuments.AUTORITY,MyDocuments.ROOT), DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR,MyDocuments.INITIALURI);
                    fileUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(MyDocuments.AUTORITY,MyDocuments.INITIALURI);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    errorMsg(MyDocuments.falloCrear + e.toString());
                }
        }else{
            file = new File(a);

            file.setWritable(true);
            };

            String StfileR = "arduino_data_resumen.bin";
            String StfileT = "arduino_data_tiempo.bin";
            String StfileH = "arduino_data_humedad.bin";
            String StfileL = "arduino_data_luz.bin";
       try{
            createFile(fileUri, StfileT, CREATE_FILE_T);
            createFile(fileUri, StfileL, CREATE_FILE_L);
            createFile(fileUri, StfileH, CREATE_FILE_H);
            createFile(fileUri, StfileR, CREATE_FILE_R);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            errorMsg(MyDocuments.falloCrear + e.toString());
        }
        try {

            allData.saveData(context);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMsg(MyDocuments.falloGrabar + e.toString());
        }

private void createFile(Uri pickerInitialUri, String file_name, int result_option_Flag) {

    //DocumentsUI
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType(MyDocuments.MINETYPE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, file_name);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, RESULT_OK);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, RESULT_OK);
    }

    //    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_EXCLUDE_SELF,true);

    startActivityForResult(intent, result_option_Flag);


};
```

'''

The permission in the manifest are:

'''

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>         

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>         

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>         

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

'''

and the provider is:

'''

```
    <provider       

     android:name="com.sistemaderiegoandroid_arduino.MyDocuments"        

    android:authorities="com.sistemaderiegoandroid_arduino.documents"          
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"        

    android:exported="true"        
    android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">         
     <intent-filter>        
    <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />         
    </intent-filter>        
    </provider>
```

'''

To save the data in the file I use a FileDescriptor with the method getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor MODE_APPEND, this gives a ParcelFileDescriptor and with the method getFileDescriptor() I make the FileOuputStream like this:

'''

```
        FileDescriptor fdR = null;        

    parcelFileDescriptorL = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fileNameL, "MODE_APPEND", null);
                fdL = parcelFileDescriptorL.getFileDescriptor();
                arduinoDataL = new FileOutputStream(fdL);
                serializatorDataL = new ObjectOutputStream(arduinoDataL);
                for (int i = 0; i < allData.arrayDatosLuz.length; i++) {

                    serializatorDataL.writeObject(allData.arrayDatosLuz[i]);

                    serializatorDataL.flush();

                    fdL.sync();

                }
                ;
                serializatorDataL.close();
```

'''

The complete package is here:

https://github.com/DarioLobos/sistemariego

I added this grant permission request but anyway the phone don't ask for the permissions. I reset, in the applications manager of the phone the caches of restriction and permits, anyway don't ask for grant them when I install the program. Other application don't have problems while are installing and the phone request grant permissions.

'''

```
 int granted = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    grantRequested =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != granted |
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != granted |
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != granted |
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != granted;

    if ((grantRequested)) {

        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(grantDialog).setMessage(R.string.requestWriteSetting);
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            if (callBackFlag == 0) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                callBackFlag++;
                                int granted = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == granted) {

                                    grantRequested =
                                            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != granted |
                                                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != granted |
                                                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != granted |
                                                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != granted;
                                    if (grantRequested) {

                                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                                new String[]{
                                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                                                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, RESULT_OK);


                                    } else {
                                        if (grantRequested) {

                                            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(exit).setMessage(R.string.permitNotGranted);
                                            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                                                            System.exit(0);
                                                        }
                                                    });


                                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                            alertDialog.show();

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(exit).setMessage(R.string.permitNotGranted);
                                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                                MainActivity.this.finish();
                                                System.exit(0);
                                            }
                                        });


                                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                alertDialog.show();

                            }
                        }

                    });

        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    boolean grantChecker = false;


    if (grantResults.length > 0) {
        grantChecker = true;

        for (int i = 0; grantResults.length > i; i++) {
            boolean a = grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            grantChecker = grantChecker & a;
        }
    }

    if (requestCode != RESULT_OK) {

        int granted = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        if (!grantChecker & (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == granted)) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                ResumenFragment.errorMsg(permitHandling);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, RESULT_OK);

            } else {

                grantRequested =
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != granted |
                                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != granted |
                                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != granted |
                                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != granted;

                if (grantRequested) {

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);


                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(exit).setMessage(R.string.permitNotGranted);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                            });


                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
                ;
            }

        }
    }
```

'''
The Intents for result for OPENDOCUMENT and CREATEDOCUMENT give the information about the picked file in the overrided method onActivityResult. There using intent.getData() if obtained the URI for the file, then using contentResolver.openFileDescriptor can be open and with the method getFileDescriptor() do a FileOutputStream or FileInputStream sync. Like This:

'''

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


        //           The result data contains a URI for the document or directory that
        //           the user selected.
        if (resultData != null) {

            Uri uriData = resultData.getData();
         //   String fileId =DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uriData);



                    if (requestCode == CREATE_FILE_L) {
                        Data.fileNameL = uriData;
                    }
                    if (requestCode == CREATE_FILE_H) {
                        Data.fileNameH = uriData;
                    }
                    if (requestCode == CREATE_FILE_R) {
                        Data.fileNameR = uriData;
                    }
                    if (requestCode == CREATE_FILE_T) {
                        Data.fileNameR = uriData;
                    }

                    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_T) {
                        Data.fileNameT = uriData;
                    }
                    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_L) {
                        Data.fileNameL = uriData;
                    }
                    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_H) {
                        Data.fileNameH = uriData;
                    }
                    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_R) {
                        Data.fileNameR = uriData;
```

'''

I NEED TO KNOW THE PROPER WAY TO DEFINE THE ROOT DIRECTORY AND THE DIRECTORY DOWNLOAD AND THE THE PICK UP NAME AND DIRECTORY COLLECTED FROM THE INTENT RESULT. I did plenty trials without solution any help is welcome.

Comment: I need to do some explanation to find someone with experience to help me to resolve the issue.  I am an old person but I studied Java and Android for less than one year by my self, so I have other perspective and my point of view determine what have  complications or not. An open source language have to have a clear open source definition and implementation.

Comment: The problem of persistent storage data came from the starting. The Java language use the same class for files and directories. All the operative systems do it directly without security problems. To solve this the developer have to use string operations to determine if it is a file or directory since don't exist the public class directory extends file. Here appear the problem of the symbol that the operative system use for the path so is necessary ask to the operative system what it use with System.getProperty("file.separator")

Comment: After this solved issue appear the Uri. the Uri is another reference of the persistent stored data of like the path is, with more descriptive properties about the info stored. But have a algebraic issue. The transformation is not linear since is not biyective.with the File the File reference. It can be done unlimited Uri for the same File and unlimited Files for the same path. you can do this

Comment: Uri fileUri2 = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(AUTORITY,file.getPath());
                 fileUri =   DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(AUTORITY,file.getPath());

Comment: After this appear the cursor to add more properties (proyections) ) and the Matrixcursor as a database of it. This also can have Unlimited Uri for the same id. and then unlimited Uris for the samefile and unlimited Files for the same path, and the path is hidem without a a direct method and to determine if it is a path or directory have to do string operations. So unlimited documents id can access to the same file instead a directories and files permission in the files like the operative systems that don't have security issues, having or not the user and programs permit to access to it.

Comment: When it done DocumentsContract.findDocumentPath(context.getContentResolver(), uriData); Instead of give a path give you a list of paths from the top of the access permit (root of the provider) to the file requested with all the files in this way included the file path needed. So it have to be done a searching of this path in the list to use it after created the file. I am not sure about the method. I did this:

Comment: 'String filename = resultData.getData().getLastPathSegment();        
                List a =  filePath.getPath();
                String foundFilePath = null;
                for (int i=0 ; a.size()>i ;i++){
                    if (a.get(i).equals(filename)){
                        foundFilePath = (String) a.get(i);

Comment: The provider use a class to define the method to handle the database of cursors with properties. The developer have to override the method of the extended class from Document provider. One is on create that sometimes is used to create files. The provider have to be added to the manifest the android:name= is the CLASS. the android:autority= is only a STRING REFERENCE. As I understood. I need to be clarified about that.

Comment: But use onCreate to create a file is not correct because you cant issue intents to search and load with the provider.I need to be clarified about it.

Comment: HAVE TO BE USED and Override of onActivityResult that where the intent done give you an uri with the data intent.getData().

Comment: But there are no method with this Uri to access a real path if you do getPath(). Give you a String with the ids of the root and file path. since that have to be done the seching showed above if it is correct. I need to be clarified about that. Is a real question what is the inconsistency of the operative systems of file managing to add so that quantitiy of complications to add some properties to the files, like descripitons, images (the security properties are well handled in the operative systems.).

Comment: to keep the reference matrix clean I put in the onCreate.getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(ResumenFragment.fileUri,null);

Comment: But also I didn't find a clear explanation about what this NOTIFYCHANGES do.

Comment: The extended class of the provider have to be done by the developer. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider[/link]

Comment: The need to clean is importance since it can be done unlimited references for the same file in the Matrix and you can delete the file using one living all other references in the Matrix.

Comment: Also have to use it onActivity result since the user have to pick the save button. I thinks that is the flag RESULTOK but i am not sure about that.

Comment: THE NOTIFY CHANGES CANT BE PLACED IN ON CREATE OF THE PROVIDER TRHOW A NULL POINTER EXEMPTION AND THE APK DONT WORK. I WILL USE IT IN ON ACTIVITY RESULT. TO SEE WHAT HAPPENS